# Obtain property changed notifier from meta-object

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject, qmetatype

I want to write a property connector for connecting properties in C++ Qt in QML manner. It could be like this:

```
new PropConnector ( receiver, "propName", sender, "propName" );
```

The propConnector class is a small QObject class which uses sender as parent, listens on property-changed signal and sets the appropriate property of the receiver. Like this:

```
class PropConnector : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QObject *_sender;
    QObject *_receiver;
    QString _senderProp;
    QString _receiverProp;
public:
    PropConnector(QObject *sender, QObject *receiver, QString senderProp, QString receiverProp) : 
      QObject(sender)
      ,_sender(sender)
      ,_receiver(receiver)
      ,_senderProp(senderProp)
      ,_receiverProp(receiverProp)
    { 
        // Is it possible to get the proper property-changed notifier signal?
        //connect(sender, SIGNAL( on<PROPERTY>Changed() ), this, SLOT( forward ) );
    }

private slots:
    void forward()
    {
        _receiver->setProperty( receiverProp, _sender->property( senderProp ) );
    }
};
```

The only problem is, how can I discover the proper signal name for the property name I want to listen to? I guess, it is possible, but I gouldn't find out till now by reading the meta-object documentation.

**Edit:** With the suggestion of Kevin I was able to implement the class.

propconnector.h

```
#ifndef PROPCONNECTOR_H
#define PROPCONNECTOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class PropConnector : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QObject *_sender;
    QObject *_receiver;
    QString _senderProperty;
    QString _receiverProperty;
public:
    PropConnector(QObject *sender, QString senderProperty, QObject *receiver, QString receiverProperty);

private slots:
    void forward();
};

#endif // PROPCONNECTOR_H
```

propconnector.cpp

```
#include "propconnector.h"
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaProperty>

PropConnector::PropConnector(QObject *sender, QString senderProperty, QObject *receiver, QString receiverProperty) : 
  QObject(sender)
  ,_sender(sender)
  ,_receiver(receiver)
  ,_senderProperty(senderProperty)
  ,_receiverProperty(receiverProperty)
{ 
    const QMetaObject *senderMeta = sender->metaObject();
    const int index = senderMeta->indexOfProperty(senderProperty.toUtf8().constData());
    if (index != -1) {
        const QMetaProperty p = senderMeta->property(index);
        if ( p.hasNotifySignal() ) {
            const QMetaMethod s = p.notifySignal();

            QString sig = QString("2%1").arg(s.signature());
            const char *ssig = SLOT(forward());
            bool ok = connect(sender, sig.toStdString().c_str() , this, SLOT(forward()));   
            int i=0;
            i++;
        }
    }       
}

void PropConnector::forward()
{
    _receiver->setProperty( _receiverProperty.toStdString().c_str(), _sender->property( _senderProperty.toStdString().c_str() ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that information from the `QMetaProperty`

```
QMetaObject *senderMeta = sender->metaObject();
const int index = senderMeta->indexOfProperty(senderProperty.toUtf8().constData());
if (index != -1) {
    const QMetaProperty property = senderMeta->property(index);
    if (property.hasNotifySignal) {
        const QMetaMethod notifySignal = property.notifySignal();

        connect(sender, notifySignal, receiver, metaMethodOfSlot);     
    }
}
```

Untested, might not compile. `metaMethodOfSlot` would be the `QMetaMethod` for the receiver slot, obtain that in a similar way.

Comment: Cool, that helped. The receiver signal is not important, as the connection is only one-direction. The signal is fired from the connector-class itself.
I've posted the code in the question-edit.